# Centering a String on a custom component

Tags: java, swing

So I have a custom JComponent (An almost completed button, if you will). Here is the source code to the class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class LukeButton extends JComponent implements MouseListener{
    //ArrayList of listeners
    private final ArrayList<ActionListener> listeners = new  ArrayList<ActionListener>();
    Shape rec = new RoundRectangle2D.Float(10, 10, 110, 60, 50, 75);
    BasicStroke border = new BasicStroke(5);
    SpringLayout layout = new SpringLayout();
    private String text;

public LukeButton(String text){
    this.text = text;
    this.setLayout(layout);
    this.addMouseListener(this);
}
//Adds a listeners to the list
public void addActionListener(ActionListener e){
    listeners.add(e);
}
//Called when button is provoked
public void fireActionListeners(){
    if(!listeners.isEmpty()){
        ActionEvent evt = new ActionEvent(this, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, "LukeButton");
        for(ActionListener l: listeners){
            l.actionPerformed(evt);
        }
    }
}
//Listens for click on my component
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
    if(rec.contains(e.getPoint())){
        rec = new RoundRectangle2D.Float(10, 10, 100, 55, 50, 75);
        repaint();
        fireActionListeners();
    }
}
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){
    if(rec.contains(e.getPoint())){
        rec = new RoundRectangle2D.Float(10, 10, 110, 60, 50, 75);
        repaint();
    }
}
//When mouse enters, make border bigger
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){
    border = new BasicStroke(8);
    repaint();
}
//When mouse leaves, make border smaller
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){
    border = new BasicStroke(5);
    repaint();
}
public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
    return new Dimension(130, 80);
}
//Draws my button
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

    super.paintComponent(g);

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2.setRenderingHint(
            RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g2.setStroke(border);
    g2.draw(rec);
    g2.setColor(new Color(0, 204, 204));
    g2.fill(rec);
    g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g2.drawString(text, 47, 45);
}
//Methods that must be over written.
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
    }
}
```

My problem is that I do not know how to center the text variable (More or less what the variable consists of) based on the size of the String. The beggining of the String is always in a fixed point. For example if the text variable is equal to something short, the string is going to be far on the left. But if the string is too long, it goes far off the right side of the component. Does anyone know how to center my text variable so it changes it's position based on the size of the string(or a different/better solution of coarse)? Thanks for taking your time to read :)

Comment: The easy way -- use composition, and place a JLabel on top of your JComponent, and center its text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the Rectangle required to paint the text by using:

```
FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
Rectangle2D rect = fm.getStringBounds(text, g2d);
```

Then to center the text you would get the x/y positions using something like:

```
int x = (getSize().width - rect.width) / 2;
int y = ((getSize().height - rect.height / 2) + rect.height;
```

Comment: Thanks, helped a ton.